# Sharing google sheet with restrictions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've built my google sheet, and shared it with the team, the sheet has an entry point, where the user is entering some data, and balance data of the sheet is changing dynamically based on this input.

If 2 persons are using the sheet at the same time, the data will be changed based on the last guy who use this entry field, and the data the other guy seeing will be changed accordingly.

my sheet is [here](http://shorturl.at/hlnrC)
The sheet is locked except the yellow shaded cell, which is allowed to be changed by the user.

Is there a way to allow each user to see the data based on his input parameter, without getting it destroyed when  used by others!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think what you're looking for is possible as Sheets is designed to be used for collaboration and edits will always be shown in real time. Consider adding multiple sheets and assign them to each of your team members with the exact formatting and formulas as the original so they can access and input their data independently.